# BERT Text Classufication

Tags: bert-language-model

I have the code to train the bert model. But my training data is not balanced (there are 10 categories, some have 100 examples, others have 5), I added class_weights to my code, but it had no effect. Maybe I can add explicit conditions like if 'hello' in text, then this is the 'welcome' category. But I can't figure out how to do it, please tell me) I'm new to this business.

```
class_weights = compute_class_weight('balanced', classes=np.unique(y_train), y=y_train)
logger.info(f"Class Weights: {class_weights}")
class_weights = torch.tensor(class_weights, dtype=torch.float).to(device)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=class_weights)

# Training and save model
for epoch in tqdm(range(1, epochs + 1)):
    model.train()
    loss_train_total = 0

    progress_bar = tqdm(dataloader_train, desc='Epoch{:1d}'.format(epoch), leave=False, disable=False)
    for batch in progress_bar:
        model.zero_grad()

        batch = tuple(b.to(device) for b in batch)

        inputs = {'input_ids': batch[0],
                  'attention_mask': batch[1],
                  'labels': batch[2],
                  }

        outputs = model(**inputs)

        loss = criterion(outputs.logits, inputs['labels'])
        loss_train_total += loss.item()
        loss.backward()

        torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 1.0)

        optimizer.step()
        scheduler.step()

        progress_bar.set_postfix({'training_loss': '{:.3f}'.format(loss.item() / len(batch))})

    # Save state BERT model
    current_path = Path.cwd()
    torch.save(model.state_dict(), current_path / 'app' / 'api' / 'ai' / 'trained_models' / 'new_models' /
               f'fine_tuned_{model_name}_BERT_epoch_{epoch}.model')

    logger.info(f'\nEpoch {epoch}')

    loss_train_avg = loss_train_total / len(dataloader_train)

    val_loss, predictions, true_vals = evaluate(dataloader_validation)
    val_f1 = f1_score_func(predictions, true_vals)
    accuracy_per_class(predictions, true_vals)
    logger.info(f'train_loss: {loss_train_avg}')
    logger.info(f'valid_loss: {val_loss}')
    logger.info(f'F1-param: {val_f1}')`
```